# Add text inside button image and limit text to not exceed the button size

Tags: html, css, button

I have a button image of size 200x50 without text like this :

[image].

How can I dynamically update the text inside the button like this:

[image]

and make sure that the button doesn't resize and the text doesn't flow anywhere outside the button? The text could either be fewer words like 'Click here' or 'Click on this button to view more details' like in the image. Also, is there a way to set the text limit based on the button size?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give the same basic answer as the other two people already have. But far as dynamically, what language do you want to use?

The only difference in this code is I show javascript using an onClick to change the text. You could of course use event listeners or whatnot. Additionally, my code can do 1, 2, or 3 lines all centered.

(example picture of text before and after clicking:)
[image]

```js
    function changetext(num, text) {
      e = document.getElementById('button' + num);
      e.innerHTML = text;

    }
```

```css
.button-div {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/599dc.png');
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* add "cursor:" hand or other styles */
}
.button-text {
  line-height: 17px;
  /* fits three lines better */
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #F4ED3E;
  margin-top: -3px;
  /* negative margin to center */
  /* add other styles */
}
```

```html
<div class="button-div">
  <div onClick="changetext(1, 'new text')" class="button-text" id="button1">1st line
    <br>2nd
    <br>3rd
    <br>4th</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="button-div">
  <div onClick="changetext(2, 'Button Twos new text')" class="button-text" id="button2">Button with a bunch of text on it.</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="button-div">
  <div onClick="changetext(3, 'Button3s Spiffy Text is now 2 lines!' )" class="button-text" id="button3">Button little text.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks for building up on @NickyTheWrench answer. I wish Stack Overflow allow me to pick two best answers. Since this one matches my requirement closely, I am picking this as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for something like this?

```css
div.button {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/599dc.png');
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
span.buttontext {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 45px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <span class="buttontext">Click Here Now! It has a lot of text, but it won't show!</span>
</div>
```

Keep in mind, you may want to consider other ways of creating buttons. My favorite way is with pure CSS :-) Check out [this cool guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/modern-css-buttons/) for more info on that.

Comment: Yes, kind of. I have the button image already without text so the size of the button is fixed. I only need to add text dynamically. If there is lot of text like 'Click on this button to view more details', then the button should look exactly like the button I attached with image and text. The button should be able to accept text as long as it is able to. With less text like 'Click Here Now' then the text should be centered. How do I do that? Thanks for your time!

Comment: @user3376592 please update your question and add your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.button {
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/599dc.png');
 height: 50px;
 width: 200px;
 text-align: center;
}
span.title {
  text-align: center;
  color:#FF0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
}


<div class="button">
  <span class="title"><a href="#" style="">Click here on this button to <br>view more details</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer with a button link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
div.button{
width:200px;
height:50px;
background-image:url(599dc.png);
 } 
span.buttontext{
width: 150px;
height: 50px; 
margin-left: 45px;
padding-top: 8px;
color:#FF0;
display: block;
 }
```

---

```
<div class="button">
  <span class="buttontext">Click on this button to view more details</span> 
</div>
```